# How to give custom made locations for downloading the file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I just wanted to know how can i give a custom made default location for grabbing the files.
I have uploaded a file to the local database and i have binded the file to the gird also. When i press download its showing an error called **"the file is not found in location"**

If i copy the particular uploaded files to the **specified location** i can download it easily. 
So i just need to know how can i give a default location so that i can upload and downlaod the file from the same exact location.

snapshot of error: https://imageshack.com/i/ewTrmAI2j

Edited the same below code with custom made folder path. But i dont know why the file is always being asked from **bin/debug/** folder. WHy its happening like this. IS there any way i can make changes to this folder.. other than **bin/debug/** folder

Codes:

```
 private void DownloadAttachment(DataGridViewCell dgvCell)
    {
        string fileName = Convert.ToString(dgvCell.Value);

        //Return if the cell is empty
        if (fileName == string.Empty)
            return;

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
        string fileExtension = fileInfo.Extension;

        byte[] byteData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName); - - - - <<<<< ERROR HERE

        //show save as dialog
        using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog())
        {
            //Set Save dialog properties
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Files (*" + fileExtension + ")|*" + fileExtension;
            saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save File as";
            saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
            saveFileDialog1.FileName = fileName;

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string s = cncInfoDataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                File.WriteAllBytes(saveFileDialog1.FileName, byteData);
                byteData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The FileInfo() constructor only works with a full file path.  It sounds like you are trying to use the constructor with just a file name, at which point it fails when you try to read the file because its not a valid path.  There are a couple possibilities for dealing with this:

1. Create your own MyFileInfo() class inheriting from FileInfo() and add a constructor that appends your specific path to the filename.
2. Simply append the path in-line in your code as:

   var myPath = @"c:\folder\stuff\";
   FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(myPath + fileName);

Normally the path would be setup as a setting in your app.config so you could change it easily if needed.

Comment: I did as you said.. Now its showing the same error in different line. Please see the link for error: https://imageshack.com/i/iqU9G4ulp                And the code i have edited in this way: https://imageshack.com/i/p3a5VGlbp

Comment: @ hello sir...u there

Comment: The way you edited it, the line "byte[] byteData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName);" should not have changed from the original code.  It looks like something else might be going on with your path as well though from the error, but it's hard to say without knowing more about your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

codes for the binding file path to the gridview and download the file using the file path

```
private void UploadAttachment(DataGridViewCell dgvCell)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            //Set File dialog properties
            fileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
            fileDialog.CheckPathExists = true;
            fileDialog.Filter = "All Files|*.*";
            fileDialog.Title = "Select a file";
            fileDialog.Multiselect = true;

            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string strfilename = fileDialog.FileName;
                cncInfoDataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = strfilename;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Download Attachment from the provided DataGridViewCell
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dgvCell"></param>
    private void DownloadAttachment(DataGridViewCell dgvCell)
    {
        string fileName = Convert.ToString(dgvCell.Value);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {

            byte[] objData;

            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
            string fileExtension = fileInfo.Extension;

            //show save as dialog
            using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog())
            {
                //Set Save dialog properties
                saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Files (*" + fileExtension + ")|*" + fileExtension;
                saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save File as";
                saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
                saveFileDialog1.FileName = fileName;

                if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string s = cncInfoDataGridView.Rows[dgvCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    objData = File.ReadAllBytes(s);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(saveFileDialog1.FileName, objData);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```